# Stored procedure return incremented number every time its called.

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

I'm looking to create a simple web service that will make a call to a ms sql server. The database should then return a number that is simply incremented by 1 each time its called.

Notice that I'm not doing any insert or update, I just want the database to return a number every time the web service is called.

Can anyone provide the code for the stored procedure.

Thanks,

Samr

Answer (score 1):

You could store the number in a table and UPDATE it, then SELECT (return) it, each time. If you decide to do this then you would first create the table, then create a stored procedure.

You should at least attempt to create the stored procedure (having created the table).

Answer (score 0):

Sql server has a [Create Sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) capability which is a single object that increments each time you query it. Read the fine print, it increments even though your transaction roles back.